# Drawing a factor graph with colored boxes above the nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I was looking at the lecture notes for an online class, and the instructors have some nice
pictures for factor graphs and algorithms on factor graphs. One thing that was very helpful were the colored boxes above each node. I was just trying to understand how I would draw something like this. Seems like the nodes would just be circles, as per the the usual `tikz` base package. But I was not sure how to get those rectangular boxes. Are those from a particular package perhaps?

[image]

Comment: I would define a `\newcommand` with four args (colours and placement) drawing three square nodes around the nodes. Have a try and come back with your result to get some help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An empty `rectangle split` can be used as a `label` for every circle. And connections with a middle square can be done with the `markings` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, positioning, decorations.markings, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    threeparts/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3, 
    rectangle split horizontal, 
    draw, rectangle split part fill={#1},
    minimum height=.4cm, outer sep=1mm, inner sep=2pt},
    threeparts/.default={white, white, white},
    mypath/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Square[fill=white]}}},    
                postaction=decorate},
    state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=1.2cm, fill=#1, anchor=center},
    state/.default=white,
    font=\sffamily
    ]

\node[state=red!30, label={[threeparts={red!30, white, white}]:{}}] (wa) {WA};
\node[state=green!30, label={[threeparts={white, green!30, white}]:{}}, above right=of wa] (nt) {NT};
\node[state, label={[threeparts={white, white, blue!30}]below:{}}, below right=of wa] (sa) {SA};
\node[state, label={[threeparts={red!30, white, blue!30}]:{}}, above right=of sa] (q) {Q};
\node[state, label={[threeparts={red!30, green!30, blue!30}]:{}}, below right=of q] (nsw) {NSW};
\node[state, label={[threeparts={red!30, white, blue!30}]right:{}}, below right=of sa] (v) {V};
\node[state, label={[threeparts={red!30, white, blue!30}]right:{}}, below =of v] (t) {T};

\foreach \i/\j in {wa/nt, wa/sa, nt/q, nt/sa, sa/q, sa/nsw, sa/v, q/nsw, v/nsw} 
    \draw[mypath] (\i) -- (\j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know the `rectangle split` command, very nice and plain solution.

Answer (score 2):

An easy suggestion:

```
\documentclass[border=3.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    
 \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,node distance=0mm]
    
    %A
    \node at ( 0,0) [circle,draw=blue](A0) {A};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,fill=green!20,right=of A0,xshift=0.5cm](A1) {};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,fill=red!20,right=of A1](A2) {};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,fill=blue!20,right=of A2](A3) {};
    
    %B
    \node at ( 0,3) [circle,draw=blue](B0) {B};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,fill=green!20,left=of B0,xshift=-0.5cm](B1) {};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,fill=red!20,left=of B1](B2) {};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,fill=blue!20,left=of B2](B3) {};
    
    %C
    \node at ( 1,1) [circle,draw=blue](C0) {C};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,fill=green!20,above=of C0,yshift=0.2cm](C1) {};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,fill=white!20,left=of C1](C2) {};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,fill=white!20,right=of C1](C3) {};
    
    \draw [-] (A0) -- (B0);
    \draw [-] (A0) -- (C0);

 \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]